# Add values to multiple textboxes (similar names)

Tags: vb.net, loops, textbox

I was trying to find the solution for this but nothing works. I have around 650 textboxes named : A001A, A002A...A600A and I would like to put values in those texboxes for instance "example value".

I've found solution to put values in all textboxes in a form, but in mine there are those with some other values.

Next solution is this one :

```
    Dim textBoxArr() As TextBox = {A2, A3, A4, A5, etc..}
For Each tb As TextBox In textBoxArr
    Select Case tb.Text
        Case "RESNO"
            tb.Text = "-15,55,0"
        Case "DOGAL"
            tb.Text = "-15,54,0"
    End Select
Next
```

...again I have to input all names and I don't have enough freedom to manipulate values for first 50 and so on.

This is the code I have and it doesn't work:

```
For I As Integer = 0 To 650
    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls("A00" & I.ToString & "A"), TextBox)
            txt.Text = "example value"
Next
```

**error: object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT : 
I have found the solution from user Idle_Mind**

```
Dim matches() As Control
For i As Integer = 1 To 650
    matches = Me.Controls.Find("A" & String.Format("{0:000}", i) & "A", True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
        Dim cb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
        If cb.Text = "" Then
            cb.Text = "test"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: `but nothing works` <--- please be more specific. You don't want to have 650 textboxes named `A001A, A002A...A600A`. Please ask a question about specific problem you have, rather your attempted solution, which did not work (for whatever reason). Having more than a 100 controls on a form is absurd, even 50 is too many.

Comment: you do not have to put the textboxes in an array, just their names; and it doesnt have to be an array, a List(of String) would work. you could also just do something else like 1 text box (or a few) and a Combo to select the domain to work with.  users tend to balk at 650 controls

Comment: Error for the last code : object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Neolisk Textboxes are already named, just want to put values in them without having to do that manually.

Comment: This line `Dim textBoxArr() As TextBox = {A2, A3, A4, A5, etc..}` makes it look like your TextBoxes are not named A002A, etc.  When you get to the end, do you have a TextBox named A00650A?  Because that's the string you are testing.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on the line where you dim the array and see if after it and see whats in the array. The error basically means you are asking it to do something to an element that doesnt exist.

Comment: @Jovica: I understand, your best bet now is to scrap that code/UI and write new code that does it dynamically.

Comment: I am so sorry, I was writing this late last night...first part of the code is example I have found on this site...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't testing for the right key (if your TextBoxes are properly named).

Try it like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 650
  Dim key As String = "A" & String.Format("{0:000}", i) & "A"
  If Me.Controls.ContainsKey(key) Then
    Me.Controls(key).Text = "blah"
  End If
Next
```

Comment: It's not working. String is correct, but nothing happens within if statement.

Comment: @Jovica Then your statement was wrong: `textboxes named : A001A, A002A`.  Your TextBoxes obviously aren't named that, nor is it obvious which container the TextBoxes are in.

Comment: Please, I've manually named every single textbox. Every textbox is in Table Layot panel (I didn't mention that ' cause I've assumed that wasn't important). I've tested that code for enabling, color changing, value adding...and it's working. BTW this part from your code helped me a lot "A" & String.Format("{0:000}", i) & "A". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, without "A" & String.Format("{0:000}", i) & "A", code above was working with names from 100. Edited.